# Repeating date (multiple values)

Tags: 6, entities, datetime

I need to add multiple values to the repeating date field.

I have to make the schedule for a university classes. So I might have multiple groups with different schedule (different hours for each group) for the same class.

Now it's dificult to assign the schedule for each group on the same node (I don't think it is even posible), but I think at least I could have multiple values on each repeating date, e.g. each thursday at 12:00 and 14:00, and each friday 10:00 and 16:00.

I'm using the latest Drupal 6 and CCK.
I can't use Drupal 7 at the moment for this project, but minor version upgrades can be possible.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at the [office hours](http://drupal.org/project/office_hours) module. While it might not be created for your use case, it allow you to store repeatedly dates for stuff like each friday 10:00-16:00.

Comment: is it made with date api? I would have to put it into a calendar view ..

Comment: @PartySoft The two things are actually not related. The calendar is pretty complex, the best thing to do would be to test it rather than to speculate how well it would integrate.

Comment: yes, it has nothing to do. Because it doesn't use dateapi it doesn't even appear in the arguments on the calendar view. It would be very good if it would work with this and have a stop date..

Comment: couldn't I just "trick" Drupal calendar view by overriding the query?

Comment: @PartySoft What you are missing is not Data API integration (it's just some utility functions that modules can use to do date calculations) but Views integration, which will allow views to use data in calendar views and other types of views.

Comment: ok, I thought that by being of that type it would integrate, but I see it´s just an api with the date calendar. thank you ..I know where to start then. thank you